# Check if a title on Netflix is not available or has been removed

Tags: netflix

How do I look up information on if a title on Netflix just doesn't turn up in the search or if it has been removed recently?

I just tried searching on my phone for *Food, Inc.* and couldn't find it. I don't know if it has it been removed recently, not there, or delisted from search results.

Comment: Better to phrase it for a wide case, with an example, than to have it closed as too localised

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I had typed the above question from my phone and was too lazy to format it :)